# How to use TopLevel objects with out initialisers?

Tags: swift

I have seen some code in swift some thing like below. It used in a **Framework**, I'm trying to replicate the same code, as we knows getting errors. But how it is used in **Framework**?.

If we see the below code **Strings**, **Localized** and **String** code its not implementing init or **extension** of *String* ****replace(::)****  not implemented. What this code means and how to use in project as TopLevel Objects?

I can able to access this code by importing **Framework**, and I can make changes to that code.

Here is the code.

```swift
struct Profile { }

extension Profile {
    public struct Strings {
        public var title: Localized
        public init()
    }
}

public struct Localized : ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    public init(value: String)
}

extension String {
    public func replace(_ offset: Int = 4, with symbol: Character = "*") -> String
}
```

Comment: What framework are you talking about? Can you show _where_ you saw this code?

Comment: its private framework,I have shown code snippet from that.

Comment: Are you perhaps viewing the "Interface" of the code in Xcode? How did you navigate to the framework's code?

Comment: And I doubt you can "make changes to that code". Did you try typing some random stuff? If my guess is correct, it should be uneditable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What this code means

It isn't code. It's a *header*. It shows the *declarations* of some structs and methods, but not their *implementations*. It's basically a table of contents for you, the programmer, describing what structs there are and what methods they have. But you are not shown the actual code for how those methods are written. As you yourself have said, the framework is private.

Comment: hope you'r right. I never seen such use-case. It's new for me, they shown code how to use, but the the actual implementation is different right.

Comment: You haven't? Try command-clicking on the term `String` in any Swift code. You'll see exactly the same sort of thing.

Comment: yeah .. I can navigate now ... jump was not working, just restarted Xcode .. now I can see. Thank you.

Comment: @Renetik Swift doesn't really have headers, so no, it's not code. It's a sort of _description_ of some facts about the _real_ code.